# ssh error only when connected to VPN: "write: Software caused connection abort"

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

All of a sudden yesterday, I found myself unable to ssh into any server from my house while connected to my office's VPN. This problem happens with all servers I checked, whether located within my office network or outside it.

Here is the `ssh -vvv` output for the functioning case—when *not* connected to the VPN—up until the point where it starts getting into security protocols:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 93: Applying options for server_shortname
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 119: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Control socket "/Users/me/.ssh/username@server.com:22" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to server.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to server.com:22 as 'username'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
...
```

Here is the result for the non-functioning case (when I *am* connected to the VPN):

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 93: Applying options for server_shortname
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 119: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Control socket "/Users/me/.ssh/username@server.com:22" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to server.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
write: Software caused connection abort
```

Potentially relevant information:

- My machine is running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.
- I'm connected to the VPN with Tunnelblick 3.8.4 (build 5600).
- Between the last time this worked and when it started failing, I don't recall any software updates or configuration changes that could have messed something up.
- No other users of my office's VPN seem to have the same problem.
- This has persisted across a restart of my machine.
- I am able to connect to the Web normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the software that was causing the connection abort was TripMode, which indeed is designed to abort connections! I have it set to only allow whitelisted apps/processes to access the internet when I'm connected to my office's VPN. A recent update to my terminal app (iTerm) added some kind of new background process, iTermServer-3.4.1, that I *also* needed to whitelist. Once done, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your question. Had the same issue. TripMode didn't have the necessary apps ticked to allow SSH connections. Specifically, `iTermServer-3.4.3`.